# For loop inside another for loop Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How do you add one list to another, I keep running into the problem of the second list in my for loop going through the whole list.

If `aList` was `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I want the output be `1hello, 2good, 3what...` so on.

```
def function(aList):
    myList = ['hello','good','what','tree']
    newList = []

    for element in aList:
         for n in myList:
              newList.append[element+n]
```

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Expected output:

```
['1hello', '2good', '3what', '4tree']
```

Comment: So what do you want to get?

Comment: You sure you don't want `zip` `for n in myList` first?

Comment: I think he wants `[a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1] .. ]` and so on

Comment: If aList was [1,2,3,4], I want it to say 1hello, 2good, 3what... so on

Comment: Also, your alist has int elements. You can't concatenate int and str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def function(aList):
    myList = ['hello', 'good', 'what', 'tree']
    return [str(a) + b for a, b in zip(aList, myList)]
```

Output:

```
In [4]: function([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[4]: ['1hello', '2good', '3what', '4tree']
```

You also need to cast the passed in value to a string to make sure you can concatenate to the strings in your `myList`.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
aList = ['1', '2', '3']
print [element + n for element in aList for n in myList]
['1hello', '1good', '1what', '1tree', '2hello', '2good', '2what', '2tree', '3hello', '3good', '3what', '3tree']
```

or [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
aList = ['1', '2', '3']
print [element + n for element, n in zip(aList, myList)]
['1hello', '2good', '3what']
```

Comment: Sorry, I improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Your question I feel no need to add two for loop. One loop itself sufficient.

let me give two cases, which one will match your need use that.

**Case 1:** - with one for loop

```
aList = [1,2,3,4]
def function(aList):
   myList = ['hello','good','what','tree']
   newList = []

   for i in range(len(aList)):
      newList.append(str(aList[i]) + myList [i] )

   return newList
```

this will return `1hello , 2good ...`

**Case 2:** - with two for loop

```
aList = [1,2,3,4]
def function(aList):
   myList = ['hello','good','what','tree']
   newList = []

   for element in aList:
      for i in range(len(myList )):
         newList.append(str(element) + myList [i] )

   return newList
```

this will return `1hello , 1good ... 2hello, 2good`

I hope this will help...